# Scroll issue on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll

I am using bootstrap, and I noticed that if I add this css code

```
html,body{
  height: 100%; 
}
```

the scroll on mobile it is not fluid but start to be a little jerky.

I need this code because I would like to give the height in percent of some divs.

any ideas?

Comment: if the divs are direct child the body, you use min-height and see. if they are not then there is no way you can set their height in percentage. 
To use percentage the height of the parent element must be definite.

Comment: do you you why if I set the height:100% for the body and html I have this issue on the mobile?

Comment: Post the whole code, using flexbox could be a solution to this, however you sound like you want to use Bootsrap, so lets see the code.